# Is there any command to switch drivers for devices?

Tags: powershell

After windows loads its updates the driver of a devices switches to a newer version that is not working properly. If you change the driver manually via Device-Manager it works fine.

I already tried to install the driver via *.inf but it just says that the newest version of this driver is already installed. The only option is to switch it to the "old" one. The "old" one also has a different name. I also tried the commands of pnputil.

UcmUcsi.inf (old & working driver)

UcmUcsiAcpiClient.inf (new & not working driver)

```
pnputil -i -a UcmUcsi.inf

pnputil -f -d UcmUcsiAcpiClient.inf
```

Both commands dont work.

Answer (score 1):

I know how to do it with devcon.  You have to download the windows sdk to get it.  You can get the device id in device manager.

```
rem update network driver
devcon update e1d65x64.inf "PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_15BB&SUBSYS_83EA103C"
```

Comment: Devcon can also delete drivers, so once you switch you should be able to remove the old driver and prevent the problem happening again.